LST calculation on Google Earth Engine (chunk of data is absent on map)
I am using Google Earth Engine to calculate LST using the Landsat 8 data for Durban, KZN in South Africa. However a chunk of the LST data is absent for a portion of my study area . The true image and the NDVI appears fine just the LST.  How can I fix this?
